# Guardar de Char** a Uint8 Array en C++

Tags: c++

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un callback tal que :

```
int The_Callback(void *a_param, int argc, char **argv, char **column) {
```

En `argv [0]` tengo por ejemplo `p/s argv[0] = "029fb630"` que son el resultado de unir un array de Uint8 tal que: `0x02 , 0x9f , 0xb6, 0x30`.

Por tanto lo que necesitaría es una forma de pasar ese `argv[0]` a un array de **Uint8**.

He buscado por todos lados y lo que mas me he encontrado es intentar realizar una copia de memoria tal que :

```
mempcpy(uint8Array,argv[0],strlen(argv[0])+1);
```

Pero nada, esto me escribe en Uint8Array valores que no logro identificar.

Resulta que lo que me hace es como el carácter es **'0'** me pone:

`p/x argv[0][0] = 0x30 | p/s argv[0][0] '0')`.

Al realizar cualquier tipo de cast que he encontrado me pasa lo mismo, alguien tiene algún consejo o alguna solución parecida?

Comment: si la secuencia '029fb630'  está en formato `string`, tendrás que convertirla a un número antes de manejarla como tal

Comment: te refieres a que pase cada carácter a int para luego pasarlo a uint 8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> en argv [0] tengo por ejemplo **"p/s argv[0] = "029fb630""** que son el resultado de unir un array de uint8 talque : 0x02 , 0x9f , 0xb6, 0x30.

Es decir, en `argv[0]` tienes la siguiente subcadena `"029fb630"`. Dado que la subcadena son **caracteres**, si atendemos a su secuencia binaria, tendremos lo siguiente:

```
 '0'  '2'  '9'  'f'  'b'  '6'  '3'  '0'
0x30 0x32 0x39 0x66 0x62 0x36 0x33 0x30
```

Si de aquí, te quedas con los primeros 4 bytes, obtendrás el número `0x30323966` ... que no se parece en mucho a lo que tu esperas.

Lo que tienes que hacer es convertir esos caracteres en su representación numérica para poder operar con normalidad:

```
void string_to_sec(char* ptr, unsigned char secuence[8])
{
  for( int = 0; i<8; i++ )
  {
    if( isdigit(*ptr) ) // Tratamos los caracteres numericos
      secuence[i] = *ptr - '0';
    else if( *ptr <= 'F' ) // caracteres en mayúsculas
      secuence[i] = *ptr - 'A' + 10; //
    else // caracteres en minúsculas
      secuence[i] = *ptr - 'a' + 10;
  }
}

unsigned char secuence[8];
string_to_sec("029fb630", secuence);
```

El tratamiento de los caracteres no numéricos es facil:

```
'c' - 'a' + 10 = 0x63 - 0x61 + 10 = 0x2 + 10 = 12 = 0xC
```